# Read an XML file created in Excel

Tags: xml, vb.net, nodes

I am trying to read an XML file that was created in Excel (xlsx to XML), but I get an error when I try to read the nodes in the part where I give the node address within the XML, the error is as follows...

> System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: ''/Workbook
> xmlns="urn:schemas-Microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
> xmlns:o="urn:schemas-Microsoft-com:office:office"
> xmlns:x="urn:schemas-Microsoft-com:office:Excel"
> xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
> xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"/WorksheetOptions
> xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"/Panes/Pane' has an
> invalid token.'

and my code is the following.

```
    Dim cadA As String = "Workbook xmlns=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas-Microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" & Chr(34) & " "
    Dim cadB As String = "xmlns:o=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas-Microsoft-com:office:office" & Chr(34) & " "
    Dim cadC As String = "xmlns:x=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas-Microsoft-com:office:Excel" & Chr(34) & " "
    Dim cadD As String = "xmlns:ss=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" & Chr(34) & " "
    Dim cadE As String = "xmlns:html=" & Chr(34) & "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" & Chr(34)
    Dim cadF As String = "WorksheetOptions " & "xmlns=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" & Chr(34)
    Dim node As String = ""
    Dim main As String = cadA & cadB & cadC & cadD & cadE
    Dim myOpenDialog As New OpenFileDialog
    Dim varNodes, varNodesB, varNodesC, varNodesD, varNodesE, varNodesF, varNodesG As Integer

    myOpenDialog.Filter = "XML Files (*.xml*)|*.xml"

    If myOpenDialog.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

        Dim documentoxml As XmlDocument
        Dim nodelist As XmlNodeList
        Dim nodo As XmlNode
        documentoxml = New XmlDocument
        Dim strPath As String = myOpenDialog.FileName
        strPathOpened = strPath
        documentoxml.Load(strPath)

        nodelist = documentoxml.SelectNodes("/" & main & "/" & cadF & "/Panes" & "/Pane")
        For Each nodo In nodelist
            TextBox1.Text = nodo.ChildNodes(0).InnerText
            node = nodo.ChildNodes(1).InnerText
        Next
   End if
```

The XML code created in Excel is as follows and I want to read the ActiveRow subnode

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <Author>Power BI</Author>
  <LastAuthor>TEST</LastAuthor>
  <Created>2016-07-06T08:22:49Z</Created>
  <LastSaved>2023-11-10T18:35:26Z</LastSaved>
  <Version>16.00</Version>
 </DocumentProperties>
 <OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <AllowPNG/>
 </OfficeDocumentSettings>
 <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
  <WindowHeight>5460</WindowHeight>
  <WindowWidth>16224</WindowWidth>
  <WindowTopX>32767</WindowTopX>
  <WindowTopY>32767</WindowTopY>
  <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
  <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
 </ExcelWorkbook>
 <Styles>
  <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   <Protection/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s17">
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="Short Date"/>
  </Style>
  <Style ss:ID="s22">
   <NumberFormat ss:Format="Standard"/>
  </Style>
 </Styles>
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="9" ss:ExpandedRowCount="6" x:FullColumns="1"
   x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="14.4">
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Applied filters:&#10;Description is</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row ss:Index="3">
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Description</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Product ID</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Cost</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Currency</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Test A</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">ID 1</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s22"><Data ss:Type="Number">1000</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">USD</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Test B</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">ID 2</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s22"><Data ss:Type="Number">2000</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">USD</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Test C</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">ID 3</Data></Cell>
    <Cell ss:StyleID="s22"><Data ss:Type="Number">3000</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">MXN</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
  <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
   <PageSetup>
    <Header x:Margin="0.3"/>
    <Footer x:Margin="0.3"/>
    <PageMargins x:Bottom="0.75" x:Left="0.7" x:Right="0.7" x:Top="0.75"/>
   </PageSetup>
   <Selected/>
   <Panes>
    <Pane>
     <Number>3</Number>
     <ActiveRow>3</ActiveRow>
    </Pane>
   </Panes>
   <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
   <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
  </WorksheetOptions>
 </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Any ideas on how to correctly access those specific nodes?

Thank you in advance. Regards.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Images should be used only when there is no other way to demonstrate an issue, such as a rendering problem in a UI or web page.

Comment: @ken-white, sorry the image was retired and was added the XML file code, regards.

Comment: Why not use the modern `XDocument` rather than the old `XmlDocument`?

Answer (score 1):

I accessed 'ActiveRow' in the method below. Apply it

```
 Try

         Dim myOpenDialog As New OpenFileDialog

         myOpenDialog.Filter = "XML Files (*.xml*)|*.xml"

         If myOpenDialog.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

            Dim documentoxml As XmlDocument

            documentoxml = New XmlDocument
            Dim strPath As String = myOpenDialog.FileName

            documentoxml.Load(strPath)

            Dim nsManager As New XmlNamespaceManager(documentoxml.NameTable)
            nsManager.AddNamespace("ss", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet")
            nsManager.AddNamespace("x", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel")


            Dim activeRowNode As XmlNode = documentoxml.SelectSingleNode("/ss:Workbook/ss:Worksheet/x:WorksheetOptions/x:Panes/x:Pane/x:ActiveRow", nsManager)

            If activeRowNode IsNot Nothing Then
               Dim activeRowValue As Integer
               If Integer.TryParse(activeRowNode.InnerText, activeRowValue) Then

                  Console.WriteLine("ActiveRow Value: " & activeRowValue)
               Else
                  Console.WriteLine("ActiveRow value cannot be read")
               End If
            Else
               Console.WriteLine("ActiveRow Element not found")
            End If

         End If
      Catch ex As Exception
         MsgBox(ex.ToString)
      End Try
```

Comment: The OP doesn't have the inane exception handling code. Why add it?

Answer (score 1):

For this special case there is no need to use namespace manager. Simply use `name()` or `local-name()`:

```
dim ActiveRow As xmlnode = documentoxml.selectsinglenode("//*[name()='ActiveRow']")
```